# Ionic 4 [React] IonTabButton gives TypeError: Cannot read property "split" of undefined when no href

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to execute a specific function every time I click the tab button instead of routing to a different page. It has worked previously, but I'm not sure why it stopped working now.

Here's the code:

```
<IonReactRouter>
    <IonTabs>

        <IonRouterOutlet>
            <Route path="/home" component={Home} exact={true}/>
        </IonRouterOutlet>

        <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
            <IonTabButton tab="home" href="/home">
                <IonIcon icon={home}/>
                <IonLabel>Home</IonLabel>
            </IonTabButton>
            <IonTabButton tab="barcode" onClick={() => scanCode()}>
                <IonIcon icon={barcodeOutline}/>
                <IonLabel>Barcode</IonLabel>
            </IonTabButton>
        </IonTabBar>

    </IonTabs>
</IonReactRouter>
```

I've also tried taking out the "tab" part of the IonTabButton like so:

```
<IonTabButton onClick={() => scanCode()}>
     <IonIcon icon={barcodeOutline}/>
     <IonLabel>Barcode</IonLabel>
</IonTabButton>
```

The latter has worked before, but the former gives me the following error:

```
57.chunk.js:58732 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at IonRouterInner.handleChangeTab (57.chunk.js:58732)
    at IonTabBarUnwrapped.onTabButtonClick (57.chunk.js:60920)
    at IonTabButton.handleIonTabButtonClick (57.chunk.js:60753)
    at HTMLElement.handler (57.chunk.js:60100)
    at emitEvent (57.chunk.js:11000)
    at Object.emit (57.chunk.js:10982)
    at TabButton.selectTab (34.chunk.js:150)
    at HTMLElement.TabButton.onClick (34.chunk.js:133)
```

Edit:

Just in case, here's the code of the scanCode function:

```
const scanCode =  () => {
    data = BarcodeScanner.scan();
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    window.location.href = "/markAttendance"
  }
```

I also added a console.log in the first line of scanCode but nothing came out.

Edit 2:

handleChangeTab appears to be the function creating the error. This function is part of Ionic's code and not mine, but if it helps:

```
handleChangeTab(tab, path, routeOptions) {
    const routeInfo = this.locationHistory.getCurrentRouteInfoForTab(tab);
    const [pathname, search] = path.split('?');

    if (routeInfo) {
      this.incomingRouteParams = Object.assign(Object.assign({}, routeInfo), {
        routeAction: 'push',
        routeDirection: 'none'
      });

      if (routeInfo.pathname === pathname) {
        this.incomingRouteParams.routeOptions = routeOptions;
        this.props.history.push(routeInfo.pathname + (routeInfo.search || ''));
      } else {
        this.incomingRouteParams.pathname = pathname;
        this.incomingRouteParams.search = search ? '?' + search : undefined;
        this.incomingRouteParams.routeOptions = routeOptions;
        this.props.history.push(pathname + (search ? '?' + search : ''));
      }
    } else {
      this.handleNavigate(pathname, 'push', 'none', undefined, routeOptions, tab);
    }
  }
```

Comment: typeerror seems to be due to no href.. can you show what is written in scanCode() or can you verify why there is no href on your element

Comment: @Tejeshree is it not possible to have a tabbutton without href? The thing is scanCode previously worked with no href and no tab variable but didn't work reliably. Either way, i've updated my question to add my scanCode function. Let me know what you think!

Comment: please post whats there in handleChangeTab handler?

Comment: handleChangeTab is no longer part of my code but i'll add the code from the source file in my question

Comment: href is either string or undefined, so shouldnt create problem. Also,iIf you have removed handleChangeTab, shouldnt the split issue be gone?

Comment: if i leave href as a string it doesn't produce the any error, but I don't want to redirect. If i leave it undefined it causes the error in my question. I'm not sure if I should remove handleChangeTab because it's part of Ionic's source code. I'll try and comment it out and see if it helps.

Comment: ok i can't comment out the function because it's part of either Ionic or some other package's source code and i'm not sure how to access it.. I think the main focus of the problem should be why the onClick function isn't firing. If you have ideas, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I think the function is actually called, but the error is inside your function `scanCode`.

By the way, you could just write it like that:
`onClick={scanCode}`.

Comment: I've tried replacing scanCode with console.log("Something") and it doesn't display anything. I've also taken out the scanCode code and replaced it with a console.log to no avail. But just in case, I'll edit the question to include the scanCode function.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried just setting `href=""`

```
        <IonTabButton tab="tab2" href="" onClick={()=>alert("Tab 2 clicked")}>
          <IonIcon icon={apps} />
          <IonLabel>Tab Two</IonLabel>
        </IonTabButton>
```

Comment: Yep i've tried that but if it has a href, it doesn't fire the onClick function. It just redirects back to the same page.